# Service Bus Cert error

Tags: sharepoint-server, service-bus

I have an SQL, f/e web and app server. App server is running SharePoint 2013. Problem is all workflows have stopped working due to the service bus Cert expiring. I cannot find the cert anywhere only in the registry and it's not appearing on any of the other nodes. Now I cannot leave the SB farm and disconnect the workflow to resolve the issue. I've looked everywhere for solutions but because no commands are working it's impossible to get around. Any ideas anyone I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I would start [here](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm1.aspx) to understand the certificates involved in SP 2013 Workflow

Comment: Here is another [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-2013-2016-2019-how-to-replace-expired-workflow/ba-p/1148650) that might help

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus for Windows Server farm certificate is stored in SharePoint Trusted Root Certificate Authority, together with other certificates.

You can see the references below for how to renew an expired certificate or store a deleted certificate:

[Configuration How To Topics - How to renew an expired certificate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/service-bus-archive/jj712784(v=azure.100)#how-to-renew-an-expired-certificate)

[Problem with ServiceBus - certificate error.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a123f2c0-33af-4a56-9ffa-5a6296703ef9/problem-with-servicebus-certificate-error?forum=sharepointadmin)